# How to deal with widows (one-line words) in responsive design

Tags: responsive-design, word-break

I don't know if someone has faced this problem before.

Basically, imagine we have a paragraph on our website, it looks odd if there's a one-line word in the last line.

Or one word which is a combination of 2 other words, one staying at the end of a line, the other staying at the beginning of the next line (especially in Japanese it happens a lot).

I'm wondering what will be the most efficient method to get rid of that (or somehow make it look better).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps wrapping 2-worded-words in a `<span class="nowrap"></span>` that you then style with `.nowrap{white-space: nowrap;}` would solve that problem.

As far as the trailing word in a paragraph, there's no simple solution that I know of. All I would suggest is creating a media query for all major device breakpoints (1440, 1366, 1280, 1024, 764 etc) and manually styling fonts, margins, paddings etc to ensure that there is no ugly word-wrapping.

Comment: wrapping 2 worded-words should work but is it easy to wrap them automatically. I think it may be easy for English, not for Japanese.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I use all the time is to add an `&nbsp;` (non-breaking space) in between the last 2 (or more) words - that way you're essentially just saying "however you happen to break, you last 2 guys never break separately". It's really quite romantic when you think about it.